# Renault Master - locking and locking barrel issues

Tags: locks, renault, alarm, central-locking

Sorry if this has been covered before... I can't quite find an answer to my central locking issues.

Since I bought a Renault Master from 2003, I have been having issues with the locks.

To start with, I just assumed that the van did not have central locking or that if it did it was just not working at all... But then I pushed the open/close doors button on the ceiling inside the cabin and found out that there is central locking.

When I open any door with the key, it opens but does not trigger the central locking. If I lock myself in with the cabin button and then open the door with the handle it triggers the central locking to open all doors.

Another thing to mention is that opening and closing the doors with the keys (especially driver side) appear to be "heavy" (as in I need to put quite a bit of force behind it)... It is so hard that the original lock barrel and a replacement actually broke (it could unlock but it was free spinning on locking)... I am on the third barrel now!

So here is my questions:

How do I get the central locking to work when I open and close a door with the key?

Can I buy an RF remote (or key remote) to open and close the van? How do I find out which one is compatible?

The seller gave me 2 keys (just normal keys - no buttons) and a "toad" alarm dongle. Should the toad alarm, come with a remote control to open and close the doors? I am not sure about the workings of this... Earlier I locked myself in the van using the central locking button and the alarm went off... I tried to turn on the engine but it carried on screaming. I then pushed the central locking button again and it just stopped. At the time I didn't have that toad dongle on me. Still not completely sure what the purpose of this dongle is...

Thanks in advance for your help.

Leo

Comment: I don't know about a fob, but try this: When you unlock the door, try to unlock it again. On some vehicles, doing the motion the second time can trigger the rest of the locks to unlock. You can try this for locking, but would bet it wouldn't work.

Comment: Good suggestion and it might help someone reading this post in the future but it does not work with my van...

Comment: You might also try an "unlock and hold" with the key, keeping the key over in the unlocked position longer (first and/or second try) ... just throwing stuff out there which has worked on other vehicles. Those crazy Frenchmen ... you never know how they are going to build something! (J/K!)

Comment: All good suggestions but the van says no...

Comment: Sorry for resurrecting an old post- did you ever figure it out? I have acquired a 2001 Master based camper and the central locking behaves similarly strangely (button on roof locks/unlocks, turning key in door does nothing, opening door unlocks other doors) - I also have a 3rd party (I think) alarm that arms or disarms from the ceiling button when the door is open?

Comment: @James - I just gave up... I still have the van and it is just a pile of rust and expensive engine problems... The locks are the least of my worries compared to all the other issues.

Comment: Fair enough, sorry it didn't work out!